# Error in building app with Stanford NLP jars?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, stanford-nlp

I get the following error when I build my app:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

When I checked the Gradle Console, this is what I found:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Aekansh\Projects\Cortina\android-chat-starter-master\Cortibae\app\src\main\java\in\aekansh\cortibae\MessageHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"...while parsing edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.96 secs
```

So I am assuming there is some fault with my `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar` file.

In that case, here is my file structure:
root/app/nlp/stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar

and this is my build.gradle file for the app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.aekansh.cortibae"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //new ones to check out!
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile files('nlp/stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar')
}
```

Please tell me why I am getting this error. Before adding the `stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar`, the app was successfully built.

Please ask for more details, if necessary.

**UPDATE 1 
 
Reference: [This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819702/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)**

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30820138/5410043) answer, and I did everything Youngjae did. I updated all my SDKs including Google Repository, and the error still persists.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.aekansh.cortibae">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/c"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ChatBackground">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".chatscreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chatscreen"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As for the second suggestion provided by Youngjae, I did not find any duplicates in my build.gradle. I have already posted it above. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 2**

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28957412/5410043) question. None of the solutions seem to help me.

From the following notes in the logcat:

```
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>     Note: D:\Aekansh\Projects\Cortina\android-chat-starter-master\Cortibae\app\src\main\java\in\aekansh\cortibae\MessageHandler.java
> uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>     Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I figured I was using a few deprecated APIs and I fixed all the unchecked operations and deprecated methods. Now I am left with one error:

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have no idea what this error is and how I should remove it. I also used `--stacktrace` to find my error, but it showed nothing but the same error 3 times. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 3**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33939411/5410043) answer, the problem was arising because of my manual imports of libraries. So, I switched to the automatic dependency compiler.

My `gradle.build` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.aekansh.cortibae"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    //new ones to check out!
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'

    //automatic download
    compile 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.6.0'
}
```

**This also did not solve the error.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819702/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)

Comment: I have edited the question. I looked at his answer, and didn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: @MounirElfassi Can you please take a look at this question again?

Comment: after update 3, please show your updated Gradle Console